# How to Pass data from Data function to AsyncData in Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to send data from Data function to asyncData in Nuxt.

I have tried this

```
  data () {
    return {
      prevpage: null,
      nextpage: null,
      currentPage: 2,
      pageNumbers: [],
      pageNumberCount: 0
    }
  },
  asyncData ({ $axios, error, data }) {
    return $axios
      .get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=' + process.env.API_SECRET + '&page=' + this.currentPage)
      .then((response) => {
        return {
          popularmovies: response.data.results
        }
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        error({
          statusCode: 503,
          message: 'Unable to fetch event'
        })
      })
```

I also tried this

```
  .get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=' + process.env.API_SECRET, {
    params: {
      page: this.currentPage
    }
```

I also tried to use ES6

```
  .get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=${process.env.API_SECRET}&page=${this.currentPage}`)
```

But it always returned error

> Cannot read property 'currentPage' of undefined

Comment: The asyncData hook is executed before the data option is available

Answer (score 2):

You can use the VueX store

```
asyncData ({ $axios, error, data , store}) {
   // access to data

   console.log(store.state.myData)

 })
```

in your mounted set data to the store

```
mounted(){

this.$store.setData(this.pageNumberCount)


}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to add a URL parameter for the page, instead of having it inside the local state. Then you can use it with the `params` property of the context object passed to `asyncData`.

For example, you can use something like `/page/_currentPage.vue` inside your pages directory, then you can rewrite your asyncData declaration to be something like `asyncData ({ $axios, error, data, params})` and use `params.currentPage` to access the page received as a parameter. You should also check if it exists, and if it doesn't you can just set the page to 1

Comment: I don't understand, can you please elaborate. Thanks

Comment: I've added an example. Feel free to ask again if it doesn't help